# How can I call a static method from a class if all I have is a string of the class name?

Tags: php

How would I get something like this to work?

```
$class_name = 'ClassPeer';
$class_name::doSomething();
```

Comment: $class_name::doSomething(); works fine for me.

Comment: @VolkerK, I'm getting a T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM error when I try.

Comment: @VolkerK: that syntax works since PHP 5.3

Comment: It appears that if you're using a namespace, it must be included in the class name variable $class_name, even when calling invoking the function within the same namespace: $class_name = 'MySpace\ClassPeer' or $class_name = NAMESPACE . '\ClassPeer' (NAMESPACE is a magic constant preceded and followed by two underscore characters not displayed here.)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Depending on version of PHP:

```
call_user_func(array($class_name, 'doSomething'));
call_user_func($class_name .'::doSomething'); // >5.2.3
```

Comment: Perfect. I'm using the second example above to call the static method. Thanks jimyi!

Comment: @jimyi, which is faster?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the first one is faster since it avoids parsing the string to retrieve the class name and method name. But that's just a guess, maybe the array initialization takes more time than parsing the string.

Comment: Just had need for this functionality and the first comment on OP's question was right - you can just call `$class_name::method()` and it works. Unfortunately PHPStorm doesn't agree and highlights it as a warning...

Answer (score 21):

Use [`call_user_func`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).  Also read up on PHP [`callbacks`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).

```
call_user_func(array($class_name, 'doSomething'), $arguments);
```

Answer (score 21):

To unleash the power of IDE autocomplete and error detection, use this:

```
$class_name = 'ClassPeer';

$r = new \ReflectionClass($class_name );

// @param ClassPeer $instance

$instance =  $r->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();

//$class_name->doSomething();
$instance->doSomething();
```

Basically here we are calling the static method on an instance of the class.

Answer (score 13):

These answers are all outdated:

```
<?php

class MyTest{
    
    public static function bippo(){
        echo "hello";
    }
}

$a = MyTest::class;
$a::bippo();
```

works fine

Comment: Its true, this works even down to php 5 - see https://3v4l.org/ind2m

Comment: This does not answer the question: how to invoke a class function when all you have is the class name as a string.

Answer (score 5):

After I have almost missed the simplest solution from VolkerK, I have decided to extend and put it in a post. This is how to call the static members on the instance class

```
// calling class static method
$className = get_class($this);
$result = $className::caluclate($arg1, $arg2);

// using class static member
foreach ($className::$fields as $field) {
  :
}
```

Comment: In a specific case I had, where the *classname* was stored in a `const` of a class, it's not possible to do `self::CLASSNAME::methodToRun()`, but it's necessary to wrap the constant so that it's evaluated before trying to execute the method. Do `(self::CLASSNAME)::methodToRun()` instead; or store the value in a variable first.

Answer (score 4):

Reflection (PHP 5 supports it) is how you'd do this. Read that page and you should be able to figure out how to invoke the function like that.

```
$func = new ReflectionFunction('somefunction');
$func->invoke();
```

[Documentation Link](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.invoke.php)

Answer (score 1):

if you need to adjust the namespace

```
$call = call_user_func(array('\\App\\Models\\'.$class_name, "doSomething"));
```